# for each loop listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, foreach, listviewitem

I am trying to figure out how to write a for each statement so that this will keep looping through finding all the users, since right now, it only finds he first user.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
Dim item As New ListViewItem
item = New ListViewItem
Dim itm As New ListViewItem(objRecordSet.Fields("sAMAccountName").Value().ToString)
itm.SubItems.Add(objRecordSet.Fields("givenName").Value().ToString)
itm.SubItems.Add(objRecordSet.Fields("SN").Value().ToString)
ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
```

Comment: there is no loop there and there is no code to find anything; it just adds am LVI, so it is unclear what could be wrong; are you asking how to loop on the recordset to add a number of items?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm asking.  I'm sorry I wasn't clear.  I'm trying  to loop on the recordset to add more items to the list.  I was searching online and nothing I tried worked, so I am guessing I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for the task you are asking (not tested)

```
If Not (objRecordSet.EOF And objRecordSet.BOF) Then
    objRecordSet.MoveFirst
    While Not objRecordSet.EOF
        Dim itm As New ListViewItem(objRecordSet.Fields("sAMAccountName").Value().ToString)
        itm.SubItems.Add(objRecordSet.Fields("givenName").Value().ToString)
        itm.SubItems.Add(objRecordSet.Fields("SN").Value().ToString)
        ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
        objRecordSet.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
```